# How to remove / omit `mongo-express` node express middleware's output in the terminal?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, middleware

In the browser, when I visit my local installation of the [Mongo-Express](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express) Web Interface, I see something like this:
[image]

In the console however, it prints out every resources requests used on the page (images, css, scripts, etc.)

[image]

Is there anyway to **turn-off** or **omit** this?

I've tried digging into the `mongo-express` config file for a way to disable the output, but no dice.

**Note:** In case it helps, I'm using it in my NodeJS express app like so:

```
app.use('/mongo-express', mongo_express(mongoConfig));
```

My guess is that I'd have to change something in the `mongoConfig` JS file (it's obtained via a `require(...)` call somewhere higher in the code), or start the `mongod` service with some sort of 
`--quiet` flag (*but to me, that sounds like it has nothing to do with controlling the output in express's middleware, since `mongo-express != mongod service`*).

Comment: I'm also open to alternatives to `mongo-express` if there are better MongoDB Web-based interfaces available in NodeJS.

Comment: Tried MongoChef / Studio 3T, never looking back! :) https://studio3t.com

Comment: How about Keystone, if you use mongoose?

Comment: @ZeroCho hmm never heard of KeystoneJS before, but after watching this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPXDFeUEk3g), seems like it's a bit overkill. Not entirely sure if there's an easier way to set it up, but was mostly interested in a quick module installation that I can require / tie in my existing Node express routes.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is quite old, I just stepped over it.

Find the entry

```
logger: {}
```

in the config-file near the end and change it to

```
logger: {
    skip: function(req, res) {return true;}
}
```

This tells the morgan-logger to skip all output. With this function you can control what is logged based on the request or response object. Return `true` to suppress logging and return `false` to write to the log.

Comment: Helped me a lot. Thank you.